# Performance core-plot

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-plot

I have tabbar with 2 inset. In first inset i have image on which 8 labels with some values. I wrote method thath remove first object from an array and add random object to end of array.
I use this method for add values for labels. Every 2 seconds it updates.

```
-(void) imageBackground
{
    labValues1.text = [[[CPDConstants sharedInstance].arr lastObject] stringValue];
    labValues2.text = [[[CPDConstants sharedInstance].arr2 lastObject] stringValue];
    labValues3.text = @"9.76";
    labValues4.text = @"9.81";
    labValues5.text = [[[CPDConstants sharedInstance].arr3 lastObject] stringValue];
    labValues6.text = [[[CPDConstants sharedInstance].arr4 lastObject] stringValue];
    labValues7.text = @"10.01";
    labValues8.text = @"10.03";

   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(imageBackground)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` i create array [CPDConstants sharedInstance].arr with some start values and use timer for updating the values

```
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(generator) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)generator
{
    [[CPDConstants sharedInstance].arr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    NSInteger countKiss=arc4random()%30;
    [[CPDConstants sharedInstance].arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(20+countKiss)]];
}
```

In second inset i have 4 plot. I devide the screen on 4 view and add the graphs. and call

```
[graph reloadData];
[graph2 reloadData];
[graph3 reloadData];
[graph4 reloadData];
```

And it's work. 
But it's very slow. I make it for creating real-time plot with dynamic data.

How can I make it faster? I think the main problem is in updating labels. If my program work  more than 10-15 sec it becomes very slow and i can change inset, it doesn't responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the "Real Time Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app for one approach. Instead of loading all of the plot data and labels on every update, tell the plots to update only the points that change. Use `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` to insert the new data points and `-deleteDataInIndexRange:` to remove any old data that you no longer need.